# Where can I get fungal extracts?

Tags: mycology, methods, materials

Does anyone know how I can get fungal extracts from fungal isolates? I have isolates in PDA slants and I'm gonna need to get their respective extracts to impregnate in sterile discs. I'm a novice in the field and all the help I can get will be greatly appreciated.